# How to impl a drm scheme?

Tags: drm

Resources about how to implementing DIY DRM scheme on the web are limited.

Requirements:

- Convenience and not annoying for the User
- User account for update and online features
- Watermarks
- Product key
- Code obfuscation
- Respect [fair dealing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fair_dealing)

Any resources?

Answer (score 0):

That is likely because a lot of DRM relies on security by obscurity at least somewhat, and therefore being open is sort of defeating the point a bit.

However, there are at least 2 relatively open DRM systems that have specs publically on how to implement at least part of it.

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OMA_DRM
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marlin_(DRM)

They might be considered a good place to start if you are looking for how to implement DRM.

You are not likely to see a lot of public discussion on the code obfuscation parts though. But in terms of the infrastructure and how to define rights, they might be provide good templates.